# bootable USB not booting

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I want to install Windows 10 on my actual notebook running arch linux.

If I boot from the usb I got back into UEFI or I get the message "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert..."

I did the usb bootable with the dd command from linux:

```
sudo dd if=/path/windows.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

What I already tried:

- other usb device
- tested all ports
- settings UEFI to default
- enabled CSM
- secure boot disabled

What else could I try?

Comment: See if you can disable Secure Boot temporarily in BIOS and get it to boot that way.

Comment: It sounds like something went wrong when you tried to make it bootable. Can you please describe the process you went through to make the USB drive (where you got the .ISO, what filesystem the drive uses, etc.)?

Comment: @SamForbis I added the way I made it bootable. The iso I got from microsoft official download and the filesystem is udf.

Comment: @MaxNeumann It should be exFAT formatted. The ISO is formatted in UDF, but you must copy/paste the contents of the ISO to the exFAT formatted drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) to create bootable windows USB in linux

Make sure to select NTFS instead of fat is iso size more than 4 GB